# word-wrap -- using `'cursor t` when overlay 'after-string at end of visual line

Tags: emacs, elisp, overlay

**PROBLEM**:  When point is at the end of a visually wrapped line (but not at the very end of the line), the cursor does not respect the `cursor t` setting of the overlay `after-string` -- i.e., the cursor appears at the beginning of the *next* visually wrapped line, instead of the very end of the *current* visually wrapped line.

In this example / question, let us assume that the variable `word-wrap` is `t` and the variable `truncate-lines` is `nil`.  It does not have to be `visual-line-mode` that is active, but it certainly could be.  The goal is to extend a horizontal ruler from the end of the visual line to the right window edge, and fix the problem that occurs when point is at the end of the visually wrapped line (but not at the very end of the line).

The following code works in every situation **except** when the cursor is at the end of the visually wrapped line (but not at the very end of the line).  Programmatically, how can the cursor remain visually located at the beginning of the overlay `after-string` in this circumstance?

```
(defun example ()
(interactive)
  (let* (
    peovl
    peovl+1
    (col-eovl
      (save-excursion
          (let ((movement-indicator (vertical-motion 1)))
            (when (= movement-indicator 1)
              (backward-char 1)))
          (setq peovl (point))
          (setq peovl+1 (1+ peovl))
          (- (current-column) (progn (vertical-motion 0) (current-column)))))
    (current-underline-length (- (window-width) col-eovl))
    (underline (propertize (char-to-string ?\u2009)
          'display `(space :width ,current-underline-length)
          'face '(:underline "blue")
          'cursor t)))
  (remove-overlays)
  (unless (= peovl (point-at-eol))
    (overlay-put (make-overlay peovl peovl+1) 'display ""))
  (overlay-put (make-overlay peovl peovl) 'after-string underline)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding an overlay with an `'after-string` property to a space character (i.e., the number 32 character code) at the last point of a visually wrapped line, the cursor will **skip over** the overlay entirely.  The `cursor t` property will be disregarded.

The solution/workaround is to use a `'display` property instead when attempting to achieve the visual effect described by the original poster.

```
(defun example ()
(interactive)
  (remove-overlays)
  (let* (
    result
    peovl
    peovl+1
    (opoint (point))
    (peol (point-at-eol))
    (underscore "_")
    (col-eovl
      (save-excursion
          (let ((movement-indicator (vertical-motion 1)))
            (when (= movement-indicator 1)
              (backward-char 1)))
          (setq peovl (point))
          (setq peovl+1 (1+ peovl))
          (- (current-column) (progn (vertical-motion 0) (current-column)))))
    (current-underline-length (- (window-width) col-eovl))
    (eol-underline (propertize (char-to-string ?\u2009)
          'display `(space :width ,current-underline-length)
          'face '(:underline "blue")
          'cursor t))
    (underscore-concatenated
      (progn
        (dotimes (i current-underline-length)
          (setq result (concat underscore result))) result))
    (wrapped-peovl-underline (propertize underscore-concatenated
          'face '(:foreground "blue")
          'cursor t)) )
    (if
        (and
          (= opoint peovl)
          (not (= peovl peol)))
      (overlay-put (make-overlay peovl peovl+1) 'display wrapped-peovl-underline)
      (unless (= peovl peol)
        (overlay-put (make-overlay peovl peovl+1) 'display ""))
      (overlay-put (make-overlay peovl peovl) 'after-string eol-underline))))
```